# Multiple assignment in JavaScript? What does `[ a, b, c ] = [ 1, 2, 3 ]` mean?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

For a project, a developer sent us a JS file with code similar to this:

```js
var myList = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
var a, b, c;

[ a, b, c ] = myList;
```

It works in Opera 10.30, and Firefox 3.6.x, but it’s not okay for Opera 10.60, and Chrome.

It’s just curiosity: do you have any reference or link that says this code is compliant to the ECMAScript standard or not?

Comment: I'm pleased to find that the feature has been introduced to desktop Chrome since Chrome version 49 (https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4588790303686656 ). I've verified it in my Chrome extension code https://github.com/chuan6/webXi/commit/8283ea713ea5c8c050750b5cd64c6f922817f727#diff-b227432cc34ef4d8e3d6af1fcd6b24f5R86 .

Comment: In case somebody comes here wondering, you can do `var [a,b,c] = myList;` with the same effect.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a feature called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), which was added in JavaScript 1.7 and ECMAScript 6. It is not a part of ECMAScript 5: [What is cross browser support for JavaScript 1.7's new features? Specifically array comprehensions and the "let" statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330498/what-is-cross-browser-support-for-javascript-1-7s-new-features-specifically-arr)

Answer (score 14):

Here’s an update on the subject: as of [JavaScript version 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7), destructuring assignments are supported by all major browsers: see [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility).

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.
>
> – [MDN’s documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

So you can do:

```
let a, b;
[a, b] = ["Hello", "World"];

console.log(a); // "Hello"
console.log(b); // "World"
```

Or simply in one line if you're defining the variables:

```
let [a, b] = ["Hello", "World"];

console.log(a); // "Hello"
console.log(b); // "World"
```

Answer (score 5):

This is destructuring assignment, available in Javascript 1.7 (mozilla) and some newer browsers: http://www.robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-1.7.html#destructuring-assignment

Answer (score 2):

Opera's older "futhark" JavaScript engine had support for this, but it was dropped in the new engine "carakan", because it was non-standard, not required on the web, and would complicate the new and very fast implementation.