# Syntax for destructuring arrays into function parameters in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There is plenty of documentation on how to destructure objects passed as function parameters in Javascript 2015 / ES6 / ECMAScript 2015, with a function like this:

```
function foo({a, b}) {
   console.log(`a: ${a}, b: ${b}`);
}
```

But how do you destructure an *array* parameter?

Comment: Honest question: Why is this downvoted? I had trouble finding a straight answer to this question either on SO or on the general internet, and I believe syntax questions are legitimate for SO.

Comment: The documentation on how to destructure object parameters will certainly also cover how to destructure array parameters.

Comment: @torazaburo then a link to that documentation would be a valid answer to the question

Comment: @JBCP: Can you link the documentation that you found that only covers objects?

Comment: Here's an example of arrays being destructured: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3986348/1048572

Comment: This certainly covers all the issues: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html

Comment: Ok, buried in two lines of that documentation (10.1.3 Where can destructuring be used?) there is an example of an array being destructured as a function parameter. I still think it is a legitimate question since although the syntax might be obvious, the documentation is not explicit, and having to read the language specification is not always reasonable.

Comment: I thought exactly the same thing. Endless examples of array assignment destructuring, but almost nothing on array parameter destructuring.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The correct syntax to destructure an array parameter is:

```
function foo([a, b]) {
   console.log(`param1: ${a}, param2: ${b}`);
}
```

It can be called like this:

```
 foo(['first', 'second']);
 // Will output:
 // param1: first, param2: second
```

According to [*Exploring ES6*, section 11.6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_parameter-handling.html), you can use this to destructure parameters within arrow functions as well:

```
const items = [ ['foo', 3], ['bar', 9] ];
items.forEach(([word, count]) => {
    console.log(word + ' ' + count);
});
```

Comment: If we want to capture the remaining parameters in the array, we can use rest operator:`function foo([a, b, ...args])`

Comment: Thank you.  I had it right for my part, but I had other issues that were causing void to be passed into each element of my array.  (`map` instead of `tap` in rxjs).  So I thought I had it wrong.

Comment: Note the second example will output: `foo 3` and `bar 9`