# Unpacking an array in a function call

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to unpack an array as arguments for a function?

For example in python if I have:

```
user = ["John", "Doe"]

def full_name(first_name, last_name):
    return first_name + last_name
```

Then `full_name(*user)` unpack my `user` array and pass each of its items as argument of `full_name`.

Is that possible to achieve such a behavior in JavaScript/TypeScript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax for destructuring arrays into function parameters in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36961080/syntax-for-destructuring-arrays-into-function-parameters-in-es6)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the `...spread` operator.

```
const user = ["John", "Doe"] as const

function fullName(firstName: string, lastName: string): string {
    return firstName + lastName
}

fullName(...user)
```

Note the `as const`.

In order for this to have type safety in Typescript, the array needs to be a two item tuple of type `[string, string]` and not just an array of unknown length like `string[]`. This is because in order to guarantee type safety there must be at least 2 strings in that array in order to satisfy both arguments. `as const` forces typescript to treat that array as a tuple with known strings and length instead.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=18#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgJxgXhgbQEQCkQAWY2ANDNgCIiLYC6MAhhDKJFAFDsBmcYwUAS3AweAG1EA5BgFtEACi4Dk0KbIBcMaMgFgA5mVFMoqxBq07dASjNRtemAG92MFzGSIocZGBFKVMxBgAahhDf1l2AF9OMUkAuQA6JIQUSyA)

Answer (score 3):

You could either apply array desctructuring on the parameter of the `full_name` function:

```
const user = ["John", "Doe"];

const full_name = ([first_name, last_name]) =>
    first_name + last_name;

full_name(user);
```

or use the spread operator (`...`) when you call `full_name` with the array parameter.

```
const user = ["John", "Doe"];

const full_name = (first_name, last_name) =>
    first_name + last_name;

full_name(...user);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the `...` (spread) operator.

```js
const user = ["John", "Doe"]

function fullName(firstName, lastName) {
    return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
}

fullName(...user);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Destructuring assignment. Like this:

```
const full_name = (arr) => {
    const [firstname, lastname] = arr;
    return `${firstname} ${lastname}`;
};

var user = ["John", "Doe"];
console.log(full_name(user)); // result: John Doe
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to meet the criteria posed in the OP: "Then full_name(\*user) unpack my user array and *pass each of its items as argument of full_name*."