# What kind of construct/pattern is this type of assignment?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following block of borrowed code in one of my JS projects:

```
return Promise.all(accessoryGetMethods)
.then(systemAccessories => {
  const [partitions, sensors, lights, locks] = systemAccessories
  return {
    id: res.data.id,
    attributes: res.data.attributes,
    partitions: partitions.map(p => p.data),
    sensors: typeof sensors != 'undefined' ? sensors.data : [],
    lights: typeof lights != 'undefined' ? lights.data : [],
    locks: typeof locks != 'undefined' ? locks.data : [],
    relationships: rels
  }
})
```

In particular, what kind of assignment pattern is the line:

```
 const [partitions, sensors, lights, locks] = systemAccessories
```

Comment: It's called array destructuring.

Comment: More specifically https://stackoverflow.com/q/3986348/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe - ***Wow***

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ??

Comment: @jonrsharpe - As in: ***Wow***, I'd either forgotten or never learned that JavaScript 1.7 had destructuring, so I'm amazed to see a 10-year-old dupetarget. Of course, it's arguably different now (iterators), but...