# async call to function with multiple returns

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

An async function I am dealing with, returns multiple values in array

```
const funcName = async function (arg) {
  ...
  return [val1, val2];
}
```

While calling this function, I find that it is *not* possible to directly access individual return values in a syntax:

```
result1 = await funcName(arg)[0]  
result2 = await funcName(arg)[1]
```

The only way (known to me so far) it works, is to break it down:

```
result = await funcName(arg)
result1 = result[0]
result2 = result[1]
```

Is there a way to "collect" the return directly in a single LOC?
(closely, like `r1 = await fn(x)[0]`)
This works obviously for sync variant, and keeps code much precise, clean, while readable.

Bonus ask: any clue why direct array access is not supported?
By intent, or just missed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for the `await` operator is

```
await UnaryExpression
```

Which means that the *entire* expression will be evaluated before handing over to `await`. Here is a breakdown of what happens when you have `await funcName(arg)[0]`

1. `funcName(arg)` returns a promise.
2. `[0]` is the square brackets notation used *on* the promise. So, it's getting the property `0` from the promise object.
3. Since there is no such property, the result of the expression is `undefined`.
4. `await` is called on `undefined`. Since this isn't a promise, it's treated as if a `Promise.resolve(undefined)` and so there is nothing to wait to complete.
5. Code execution continues before the actual promise object from step **1.** is complete.

You can force `await` to consider the returned promise, if you surround the correct part of the expression in brackets or to only use it on the expression that returns a promise:

```js
const simpleAsync = async function () {
  return ["one", "two"];
}

async function main() {
  const foo = await simpleAsync()[0];
  const bar = (await simpleAsync())[0];
//            ^                   ^ 
  const baz = await simpleAsync();

  console.log("foo:", foo);
  console.log("bar:", bar);
  console.log("baz:", baz);
}

main();
```

However, if you want to directly get both return values, you can simply use [destructuring for a multiple assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986348/multiple-assignment-in-javascript-what-does-a-b-c-1-2-3-mean):

```js
const simpleAsync = async function () {
  return ["one", "two"];
}

async function main() {
  const [a, b] = await simpleAsync();

  console.log("a:", a);
  console.log("b:", b);
}

main();
```

This way `await` is called with an actual promise, rather than a non-promise and *after* that is resolved, the `a` and `b` variables will be assigned.

Answer (score 1):

```
const [result1 ,result2]= await funcName(arg)
```

Comment: decontruct... 

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const [val1, val2] = await funcName(arg);
```