# Array comprehension in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, python, list, list-comprehension

I was wondering what the neatest way would be to convert (from Python) a list comprehension into Javascript. Is there anything which will make this readable and not a mess?

```
    non_zero_in_square = [ grid[row][col]
                           for row in range(start_row, start_row+3)
                           for col in range(start_col, start_col+3)
                           if grid[row][col] is not 0
                         ]
```

*This is quite a good example of a list comprehension, as it has multiple `for`s and and an `if`.*

I should add that the `range` bit is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8273091) (I can't live without `range`).

Comment: As a JavaScript developer who wouldn't know Python if it came up for a chat at the bus stop, that's some funky ass syntax you Pythonistas have got there.

Comment: Notice that JavaScript 1.7 has [Array Comprehension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Array_comprehensions_%28Merge_into_Array_comprehensions%29), unfortunately are implemented only in Firefox at the moment. I hope we will get soon in other browsers as well (see [harmony](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:array_comprehensions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it would be somewhat messy to do this with the `.map()` method, because the outer calls really need to return arrays.  Thus you're probably best with the pedestrian:

```
var nonZero = [];
for (var row = startRow; row < startRow + 3; ++row)
  for (var col = startCol; col < startCol + 3; ++col)
    if (grid[row][col] !== 0) nonZero.push(grid[row][col];
```

Comment: Right. Plus I would enclose it in a self-executing function assigned to the variable to protect `nonZero`

Comment: @elclanrs yes I agree; this assumes some sort of scope akin to the OP, but if it were some sort of tool then `nonZero` should be a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

Coffee script support list comprehension syntax and is probably the neatest as it follows syntax exactly.  Unfortunately it is an intermediary and would be compiled to multi line javascript

http://coffeescript.org/#loops

They show you how it coverts to vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 0):

[Mozilla JS Documentation, ES 1.7 supports them natively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_comprehensions).

Example:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var doubled = [i * 2 for (i of numbers)];
```

Comment: You won't find any support today in popular browsers except Firefox: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/   .