# How to create a grid in JavaScript using a one liner for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Good evening programmer community!
Is it possible to create a one liner array in Javascript. To make my question clearer, I would like to emulate the following one liner that I usually do in Python on Javascript:

```
>>> arrAy=[['_' for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]
```

which gives the following result:

```
>>> for i in arrAy:
    print(i)
>>> [['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'],
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']]
```

Thank you

Comment: Well you can do everything in 1 line in JavaScript technically, just separate statements with `;` so `for(var i = 0; i < arrAy.length; i++) { console.log(arrAy[i]); }` is valid

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) doSomething(i, j);` is definitely a oneliner

Comment: I really wanted this to work `var myArr = new Array(10).map(function() { return new Array(10).map(function() { return "_"; }); });` but due to the way that `new Array()` initilizes the array with `undefined` values and how `map()` only runs the provided function on array indexes with values, it doesnt :(. You could do `var anArray = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]].map(function(arr) { return ["_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_"]; });` though :)

Comment: @PatrickBarr, I may not have perfectly understood your idea, but it seems to me that you don't quite get my question (I'm sorry for any ambiguity). I don't need to display the array arrAy, but to create it with a oneliner.
Something like:
`for ( i amount of iterations ) {for ( j amount of iterations ) { '_' }}`
Thank you.

Comment: Why does it have to be a one-liner?

Comment: @Barmar, it is very important for me to write minimalistic code that is clean and does the job.

Comment: @Chihab sorry I wasn't trying to answer, just point out that javascript doesn't exactly follow "lines" like conventional languages, I think you should look at le_m's answer below, and javascript minification if you're looking for minimalist code

Comment: In what context is this more important than writing clear code? If you need to reduce the download time, use a minifier.

Comment: Thank you guys, I didn't know about code minifiers.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you would need to define a [range generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273047/javascript-function-similar-to-python-range) as there is no built-in equivalent:

```
function* range(n) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) yield i;
}
```

Then, you would need to replace the [generator comprehension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Generator_comprehensions) with for...of loops as comprehensions are a non-standard feature in JavaScript and unlikely to be added to ECMAScript in the future.

```
const arrAy = [];
for (let i of range(10)) {
  let row = [];
  for (let j of range(10)) row.push('_');
  arrAy.push(row);
}
```

This is very close to the generator based python original, but neither idiomatic JavaScript nor a one-liner. Also, you don't really need the generators as you store the whole result in an array anyway.

A non-generator based one-liner could look as follows:

```
const arrAy = Array.from({length: 10}, () => Array.from({length: 10}, () => '_'));
```

or shorter

```
const arrAy = Array.from({length: 10}, () => Array(10).fill('_'));
```

Of course, as outlined in the comments, you could squeeze the plain old for-loop into a one-liner, too, but that's the job of a code minifier, not the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with the magic of `map` and `fill`.

```js
const grid = (width, height, value) => new Array(width)
  .fill(null)
  .map(v => new Array(height)
    .fill(value));
const grid10x10 = grid(10, 10, "_");
console.log(grid10x10);  // tada!
```