# How To Add Properties from Arrays?

Tags: javascript

```
let person = {}

let keys = ['name', 'age', 'work'];
let values = ['Adam', 23, 'none'];

// how to make result
 person = {
 'name': 'Adam',
 'age': 23
 'work': 'none'
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? Any research, even - have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/39127989/3001761?

Comment: i have array of keys and array of values and i want create an object with them

Comment: Yes, I understand the desired outcome, but this isn't a code-writing or tutorial service. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score -2):

A simple loop does just fine.

```js
let person = {}

let keys = ['name', 'age', 'work']; let values = ['Adam', 23, 'none'];

for (const i of Array(keys.length).keys()) {
  const key = keys[i];
  const val = values[i];
  person[key] = val;
}

console.log(person);
```

Comment: That's a very roundabout way to loop over the indices...

Comment: @jonrsharpe ye 

Comment: For which read: bad.

Comment: @jonrsharpe why? Trying out some stuff I read on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273047/javascript-function-similar-to-python-range)

Comment: It's because the code obscures the nature of the loop. `for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {...}` is more readable. Also that post is from 2011.

Comment: @Andy good input, I'll keep that in mind