# Javascript: [] = 5, No Syntax Error? Why?

Tags: javascript

Yeah, it works in my firebug console. Why does something like this present no syntax error?

```
[] = 5; [] = doThis(); [] = (function() {})();
```

Just curious about why it's allowed.

Comment: It is an error in Chrome btw...I think it's just ignoring your setting and moving on along.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like Javascript in FF allows assignment using matching so you can set multiple variables in one shot:

```
[x,y] = [5,6]; // sets x to 5 and y to 6
```

"Obviously", some JS implementations are very forgiving, and will silently ignore any extra values, so this does the same:

```
[x,y] = [5,6,7];
```

and this would just not assign anything:

```
[] = [5,6,7];
```

and on top of that, it looks like FF is even willing to go with a case that doesn't match an array at all:

```
[x] = 5; // makes x undefined
```

so if you use `[] = whatever` then "nothing gets assigned an undefined value", so it boils down to just evaluating the RHS.

(Disclaimer: this is all just guessing the meaning by running stuff in FF...)

Comment: There's a detailed thread about mozilla's destructuring assignment syntax here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204444/destructuring-assignment-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

I get a "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" in Chrome. IE8 throws "Error: Cannot assign to '[object]'". FF does, indeed, not throw an error.

This is most likely just a failing of the Firefox JavaScript engine, and in any case, does not seem to affect the functionality of the array literal [].

Comment: Aha, fail on Firefox and on me, as I did not actually test this in another browser.