# What does var {u,v,w} = x; mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, language-construct

I have seen this in a piece of JS code:

```
var {status, headers, body} = res;
```

What does it do?

Comment: In some helma.org source code.

Comment: See [Destructuring assignment in JavaScript - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204444/destructuring-assignment-in-javascript).  Note that Javascript 1.7 (everything beyond 1.5, really) is effectively Mozilla-only.

Comment: ephemient: Destructuring bind was my first thought, too, but I don't see any form that uses braces `{}` in the left-hand side.

Comment: To clarify what ephemient is saying: this will only work in Firefox. Chrome, Safari, & IE all don't support this.

Comment: I tried this in Rhino (Javascript 1.7) and, unsurprisingly, it just generates a syntax error.  I don't see anything in the Javascript 1.8 or 1.8.1 release notes that looks quite like this, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nice method to set few variables at once from an object 
(open firebug and paste this to console)

```
var status=4;
var headers=4;
var body=4;

var res = {status:1, headers:2, body:3};
window.alert(status);
var {status, headers, body} = res;
window.alert(status);
```

Answer (score 1):

i read something different from your expression [here](http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/wiki/JavascriptTips) . this may help u

```
 var { a:x, b:y } = { a:7, b:8 };
 Print(x); // prints: 7
 Print(y); // prints: 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a destructuring attempt on a variable named `res`. I've never seen that in Javascript and Chrome console suggests that it's an error:

```
> var res = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
> var {status, headers, body} = res;
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Firebug console on Firefox 4b12 doesn't complain however but the statement seems to have no effect:

```
> var res = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
> var {status, headers, body} = res;
> status
undefined
> headers
undefined
> body
undefined
```