# Destructuring assignment with function arguments

Tags: javascript

```
function foo( [a,b] ) {

    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
}

foo( [12,34] );
```

Prints:

```
12
34
```

Also here:

```
 var { a:x, b:y } = { a:7, b:8 };
 console.log(x); // prints: 7
 console.log(y); // prints: 8
```

Is this method of assignment valid? Will this method bring any problems?

Also using the same technique we can swap two variables:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
[a,b] = [b,a];
```

I just wanted to know what problems will arise in future with this type of assignment? Where can I find the best reference relating to this type of assignments?

Comment: The first one gives me "unexpected token [", the second "unexpected token {" and the third "invalid left-hand side in assignment". Which browser (or other JS implementation) accepts those assignments?

Comment: All of those are invalid code. How'd you get them to work?

Comment: Since you won't tell how or where you got these to work and all the examples are clearly invalid JS, I'm going to have to vote to close as not a real question.

Comment: @Juhana the article says it is a js 1.7 code

Comment: What article would that be?

Comment: @Juhana Magical Javascript for Internet Explorer 22

Comment: @juhana plz wait i will provide u a reference to it

Comment: @juhana i have no tecnic on how to point to exaact topic so if u like to close this post,plz proceed.the code didn't work as it was said on my browser too

Comment: @Maizere - You mean this part of the document? https://code.google.com/p/jslibs/wiki/JavascriptTips#Kind_of_destructuring_assignments (hover your mouse over the heading, right-click the P that appears to the right)

Comment: @juhana [here](http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/wiki/JavascriptTips#Destructuring_assignment_with_function_arguments).

Comment: Most browsers support JavaScript 1.5. The 1.7 features are available mostly in Firefox and even then only when you explicitly specify that the script is of version 1.7 (or higher).

Comment: BTW, this seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983026/javascript-assign-array-values-to-multiple-variables

Answer (score 0):

That is a Javascript 1.7 feature, it's part of the Mozilla implementation of Javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Destructuring_assignment_(Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection)

It is not part of any ECMAScript standard (as far as I am aware) and I don't think there are any plans to make it available in other browsers; you should not use this in portable websites.

Comment: Actually, isn't it part of ECMAScript6 / harmony? http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:destructuring

Comment: From the January 20, 2014 working draft (rev 22) of the ES6 specification: "2.13.5 Destructuring Assignment
Supplemental Syntax
In certain circumstances when processing the production AssignmentExpression : LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression the following grammar is used to refine the interpretation of LeftHandSideExpression...." [(drafts)](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts)