# Getting an Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript

I'm getting an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` error for

```
[d1,d2] =[d2,d1];
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: What did you want to achieve with this statement?

Comment: Here's a (present day) javascript compliant variable swap: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201656/how-to-swap-two-variables-in-javascript

Comment: Current JavaScript doesn't work like that. But it looks like  ECMAScript 6 might.

Comment: This isn't supported by all (or afaik many at all) browsers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983026/javascript-assign-array-values-to-multiple-variables

Comment: @PatrickHofman It is some code in a library I am using.  It's in a function I probably won't use anyway since I don't foresee any need for it in the project I'm coding up.  Thanks for the compliant code.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably done a good try by looking at other posts here at SO, since your code looks much like the one at [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201656/how-to-swap-two-variables-in-javascript#comment23166580_16201730).

Unfortunately, the feature you use runs with ECMAScript 6, and that isn't supported on all browsers (yet) as you can see [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) and more specific [this one](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Destructuring).

You should use the code in the answer this comment was under.

```
d2 = [d1, d1 = d2][0];
```

Comment: "ECMAScript isn't supported on all browsers" doesn't really make sense, because in present-day parlance JavaScript is an implementation of ECMAScript. Every common browser today supports at least ECMAScript 3 ([as JavaScript 1.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history)) and, as the chart you linked to shows, most of ECMAScript 5. (ES4 was "skipped" for political reasons.) It would be more accurate to say that destructuring assignment is an ECMAScript 6 draft specification feature and [isn't supported in all browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Destructuring).

Answer (score 1):

To run this code you must wait for **ECMA6** implementation - http://www.2ality.com/2014/06/es6-multiple-return-values.html

- Documentation: https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-destructuring-assignment
- XOR swap: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Examples