# How to preserver object scope while using destructuring assignment?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider the following code:

```
const obj = {
  a: 'foo',
  b: function () { return this.a }
}

console.log(obj.a)   // 'foo'
console.log(obj.b()) // 'foo'

const { a, b } = obj

console.log(a)   // 'foo'
console.log(b()) // undefined
```

When I destruct `obj`, `b()` cannot access `a` anymore.

How can I preserve `obj` scope and allow `b()` to access it's siblings properties/methods while descructuring?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Destructuring assignment in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204444/destructuring-assignment-in-javascript)

Comment: have you got a chance to go through this . https://gist.github.com/mikaelbr/9900818

Comment: before desructuring `obj.b = ob.b.bind(obj);`

Comment: It's less about destructuring and more about the invocation context. You can try `b.call(obj)`

Answer (score 0):

@dayan-moreno-leon posted a good option.

But I just noticed that I can be handled simply by using *always static calls*:

```
const obj = {
  a: 'foo',

  b: function () { return obj.a } //HERE! :D
}

const { a, b } = obj

console.log(obj.a)   // 'foo'
console.log(obj.b()) // 'foo'

console.log(a)   // 'foo'
console.log(b()) // 'foo'
```